# Angular2 Unit Tests - test first variable value in function if it changes inside function afterwards

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I want to test the value of a variable inside a function which changes multiple time inside that function. However, whenever I expect a value of that variable, it is the value of the latest assignment. Is there a way to check what the first value is?

Here is my ts code:

```
public triggerLogin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.requestsService.login(this.userEmail, this.password)
      .subscribe( response => this.handleLogin(response))
  }

  public handleLogin(response) {
    if (_.isEqual(response, 'invalid')) {
      this.invalid = true;
    } else {
      this.invalid = false;
      this.tokenManager.store(response);
    }
    this.loading = false;
  }
```

that's my test so far (which is failing: Expected false to be truthy):

```
it('should start loading as soon as login is triggered', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(mockRequestsService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(token));
    component.triggerLogin();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.loading).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mockRequestsService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

As you can see the variable loading is first set to `true` but then afterwards in the response of the `requestsService` its set to `false`. That's why the test is expecting the value to be false. However, i want to test the first assignment for that variable.

Answer (score 2):

Units (in this case they are methods) should be tested in isolation. Only the unit under test should be real, the rest should be mocked/stubbed if necessary.

```
spyOn(component, 'login');
component.triggerLogin(handleLogin);
expect(component.loading).toBe(true);
expect(mockRequestsService.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
expect(component.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(token);
```

Since we're not testing how these two methods will play along together (this can be additionally tested in integration/e2e tests), we should be meticulous. `toHaveBeenCalled` and `toHaveBeenCalledWith` don't cover all things that may go wrong. It's better to also test that `login` is called once and with proper context (it may fail when being called like `.subscribe(this.login)`):

```
expect(component.login.calls.all()).toEqual([
  jasmine.objectContaining({ object: component, args: [token] })
]);
```

Then original `login` can be tested in another test.